# Should IEventStore Instance be Static?

Tags: c#, event-sourcing, neventstore

Just getting started with **NEventStore**.

Should I be calling `Init()` every time I want to connect (like a database connection), or should I create a `static` (or `singleton`) instance of `IEventStore` and just initialize once?

I'm aware of the example [here](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore-Example/blob/master/NEventStore.Example/MainProgram.cs), which creates a static instance (but also doesn't use the store outside of the MainProgram class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IEventStore instance should have a lifecycle of singleton with respect to your application. That is, it should be initialized once.

Comment: Thanks Damian.  Best place to ask NEventStore questions--here or on the google group (or somewhere else)?

Comment: @DamianHickey: Can you elaborate why it is a good idea to register `IStoreEvents` as singleton? We cannot find any good reason ourselves.

Comment: @D.R. It's designed as such.